# Import function which is outside of a directory

Tags: python

Based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51831324/14864907), I would like to know how to do the opposite.

For example how to import a function from `scriptA.py` into `test.py` that is in the directory `mylib` ?

Also, is it possible to put a `__init__.py` file in the root of the project directory?

```
.
├── mylib
│   ├── fun1.py
│   ├── fun2.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test.py
├── scriptA.py
├── scriptB.py
└── script_test.py
```

Comment: Design your code properly. If a function is needed by both `scriptA.py` and `test.py`, that code should be in a separate module that can be imported by both. (Or `test.py` should not be embeddd in `mylib` if it is meant to test code in `scriptA.py` as well.)

Comment: Thanks @chepner ! Yes I should put it in a separate folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to this. How you import and which module you actually execute.

For the import, put this into test.py:

```
from ..scriptA import function_name
```

Then, assuming you're executing test.py, run it from the top level directory using `python -m mylib.test`

I think that ought to do it.

EDIT: tho now I'm doubting myself slightly on the -m execution. You might have to run it from one level further up like this `python -m base_dir_name.mylib.test`

Comment: Thanks ! But when I put your solution into test.py I get `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.  And `No module named mylib.test`.

Comment: Go one level up - see the edit to my answer above. Here's how I tested it: project directory called `Test`. inside it I have `scriptA.py` containing function function_name(). inside `Test` I also have dir `mylib`, and inside that `test.py`. Then you navigate to one level above `Test` and run `python -m Test.mylib.test`